# Prove or disprove: For half-closed intervals, half the Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here's what I have been trying to prove

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b]$. Then either there is a
>   point $c_1 \in (a,b]$ such that $f(c_1) \le f(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b]$
>   or there is a point $c_2 \in (a,b]$ such that $f(x) \le f(c_2)$ for
>   all $x\in (a,b]$.

If there is a point $c_1 \in (a,b]$ such that $f(c_1) \le f(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b]$, then we are done. Suppose not, then $f$ is unbounded below. Now, I've been planning to show that $f$ is bounded above and thus show there is a point $c_2 \in (a,b]$  such that $f(c_2)= \sup \{ f(x) : x \in (a,b]\}$.

Here's the key ideas I've got so far while proving this:

Since $f$ is unbounded below, we can find $x_n \in (a,b]$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n)<-n$. Since, $(x_n)$ is bounded, by Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converging to some point $c\in [a,b]$. Thus it must be the case that $c=a$ for otherwise by the continuity of $f$, $\lim f(x_{n_k}) = f(c)$ but also have that $\lim f(x_{n_k})=-\infty$ a contradiction.

I need some hints here.

Comment: Hint: What you're trying to prove is not true. $f$ can be unbounded both above and below. Also: "If there is a point $c_1 \in (a,b]$ such that $f(c_1)\le f(x)$ for all $x \in(a,b]$, then we are done. Suppose not, then f is unbounded below." is false. Simply take $f(x)=x$ in $(0,1]$.

Comment: @Ingix Second example makes sense. But how do I find a function that is both unbounded above and below on $(a,b]$?

Comment: You want a function that oscillates a lot. I don't know, what about $\frac1x\sin\frac1x$ on $(0,1]$?

Comment: @bof That works. Thanks.